# Getting issue with meteor default app, button click counts again to 0 when refresh browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am absloute new to meteor 
I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EsDHeI327s&
I am using latest meteor on my win8.1 machine, I installed meteor with meteor window installer 
I created app with `meteor create demoapp` 
than to locate app directory  `cd demoapp` 
after that start app with `meteor` 
app started at http://localhost:3000/
I can access my app through browser but I am facing issue 
when I click button, button count values increase but when I refresh browser it again to 0

Thanks in advance for help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply because the value is not stored in a mongodb collection.

So when you refresh the page you reload the app and context is re-initialize.

Cheers,
Yann

Comment: Mongodb connection is out of the box with Meteor. Declare a collection and add your data in it :) check guide.meteor.com for more informations.

Comment: I am following this tut:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EsDHeI327s&, this guy did't mention like this

Comment: Consider following Meteor guide guide.meteor.com very useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have created a meteor-blaze application, please check your main js file. Whenever your templates gets created there is a Reactive Var which gets initialize to zero and makes your count zero. If you change that, your application count will gets start from the one you have mentioned.

On reload your template gets recreated which makes that count to the initial state. If you want to display the old count after refresh you will need to store it somewhere ex db or local storage.

Comment: will you let me know how to do it